# Finding loneliest place on earth?

Tags: distance

I would like to travel to the loneliest place on earth. I define it as being the farthest from any human settlement. The place has to be on the land and not in the sea.

I tried to google, but couldn't find any information on how to calculate it.

Comment: This needs to be move to here http://travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I guess tracing a travelling route will be my second but minor problem. The challenge here is to find geographical coordinates of the farthest point from human settlements (cities, villages etc). I guess it is somewhere in Antarctica, but what about other continents.

Comment: Are you wanting to find a way to calculate the location using GIS software, or do you just want to know where it is?

Comment: To be on-topic here *you* need to be using GIS software to try and determine it.  If you do not use GIS, then choosing that will be your first task.  Then I think you will need to find spatial data that represents what you define as "human settlements".

Comment: I actually find this a fascinating question, although as it is worded it's not on-topic.

Comment: You could pull in the ENTIRE OpenStreetMap file and figure out the furthest place from any road...?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be requesting someone else to perform a GIS task instead of asking for help to achieve a GIS task.  To learn about the scope of the site an introduction is provided in our 2-minute [Tour].

Comment: http://sometimes-interesting.com/2012/01/11/the-most-remote-island-in-the-world/

Comment: There's Maralinga in South Australia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maralinga, inside a restricted military area. Bikini Atoll or Moruroa Atoll? https://www.bikiniatoll.com/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moruroa not too many tourists there since atomic scientists blew them up with nuclear tests... you'll come back positively glowing from that trip.

Comment: Near the south pole according to your definition.Note that there are a few research stations, though

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Positively glowing!  Love it

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson - _"...not too many tourists there since atomic scientists blew them up with nuclear tests..."_. I had to read this sentence a couple of times before I realised you meant the areas and not the tourists themselves =)